# Make filename extensions hidden in specific folder (Desktop) or file (.jar)

Tags: finder, catalina, file-extensions

**I want to make all filename extensions visible (which I did in `Finder -> Preferences -> Show All Filename Extensions = true`) except the ones in a specific folder (`Desktop`), or a specific `.jar` file.**

Now, I can just hide all extensions and then just unhide the `.jar` file but I am afraid it will take too long if I can't select all the documents and *Get Info* but as far as I know, it will bring multiple *Get Info* windows as they do not have things in common?

What can I do?

I do not have Xcode installed by the way.

*MacBook Air (13-inch, Mid 2012), macOS Catalina 10.15.7*

Answer (score -1):

You can write an AppleScript that uses Finder’s `extension hidden` property to do this. See the accepted answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/399899/show-hide-extension-of-a-file-through-os-x-command-line

Comment: It's quite a stretch to come from the information in the answer you've linked to to a solution for the problem the OP asks for, even more so for people not knowing AppleScript. Can you extend your post to show a specific way of how to do this?

Comment: Thanks pion, as far as I know, I can use AppleScript in Automator, so can I unhide all the extensions in my /Users/USER/ using Automator? Because entering the file path each time I want to unhide the extension of a file will take a very long time.